# Algo to determine which attribute of an element is incorrect

Tags: python, algorithm, class, compare, element

Say I have a list of elements and each element has attributes/fields. All these attributes need to be matching specific conditions and if one attribute is non-conforming, I need to find it.

Example:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    self.type     = 'car'
    self.make     = 'Honda'
    self.model    = 'Civic'
    self.tires    = 4
    self.trims    = ['trim1', 'trim2']
    self.fetaures = {'seats': 'leather', 'steering': 'powered'}
```

Now because it is a car, it must have 4 tires and because it is a Civic, it must be a Honda and so on.
It will be really bad to test each attribute's value against each other...

What is the best way to solve this problem?

I can think of perhaps mapping a "score" or weight to each attribute and if all attributes are conforming (they all make sense with each other), I will get an expected total score X that should be the same for all elements, if an element has an non-conforming value, how do I know which attribute it is/are? If I have Z = X - Y, then how to tell that Y corresponds to a specific attribute?

How can I implement this? Is this even the best way to do it? Should I use a different data structure than an object/dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to formulate it as a constraint satisfaction problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction, https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/

Comment: is it only pairs that are conforming? if so do a counter for every value and a counter for every pair of values, if a value appear with a certain pair 95% of times, all the other are suspects

Comment: @abatea thanks for the tip. I'll look deeper into that to see if I can do something with it.

Comment: @trigonom, it actually needs to conform with all values

Comment: i think with pairs you will get all the combinations you need, (cause if (x,y,z) always come together then (x,y) also always come together